# "'cljsbuild' not a task"

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cljsbuild

using lein for clojure, attempting to use the clojurescript plugin.
followed all readme.md install steps, project.clj has

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3126"]]
  ;; lein-cljsbuild plugin to build a CLJS project  
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]]  
  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
```

I cannot seem to get lein to recognize the plugin and am not sure what is being the gremlin.

```
C:\Functional_Languages\Clojure\clojurescript_master\!work\modern-cljs>lein cljsbuild once
'cljsbuild' is not a task. See 'lein help'.
C:\Functional_Languages\Clojure\clojurescript_master\!work\modern-cljs>lein compile
C:\Functional_Languages\Clojure\clojurescript_master\!work\modern-cljs>lein cljsbuild once
'cljsbuild' is not a task. See 'lein help'.
C:\Functional_Languages\Clojure\clojurescript_master\!work\modern-cljs>lein -v
Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
C:\Functional_Languages\Clojure\clojurescript_master\!work\modern-cljs>
```

Comment: Could you please show which command you are executing and the full output you get?  Would also be of help if you show the entire project.clj

Comment: `lein help` will show the available tasks. Does "cljsbuild" appear there? It might be something with your environment, but I don't use leiningen in windows, so I can't be of much help. You could check the install instructions of leiningen to see if you missed something: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#windows

Answer (score 5):

If you use `lein new mies ...` for getting the project file, and execute the command, the automatically generated project.clj file should be modified. 
This is an example that shows the change:

Before:

```
(defproject simple "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.122" :classifier "aot"
                  :exclusion [org.clojure/data.json]]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6" :classifier "aot"]]
  :jvm-opts ^:replace ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]
  :plugins [[lein-npm "0.6.1"]]
  :npm {:dependencies [[source-map-support "0.3.2"]]}
  :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]
  :clean-targets ["out" "release"]
  :target-path "target")
```

After

```
(defproject simple "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.122" :classifier "aot"
                  :exclusion [org.clojure/data.json]]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6" :classifier "aot"]]

  :node-dependencies [[source-map-support "0.2.8"]]

  :jvm-opts ^:replace ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]

  :plugins [[lein-npm "0.6.1"] 
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]]

  :npm {:dependencies [[source-map-support "0.3.2"]]}
  :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]
  :clean-targets ["out" "release"]
  :target-path "target"

  :cljsbuild {
      :builds [{:id "simple"
                :source-paths ["src"]
                :compiler {
                    :main simple.core
                    :output-to "out/simple.js"
                    :output-dir "out"
                    :optimizations :none
                    :target :nodejs
                    :cache-analysis true
                    :source-map true}}]})
```

As you see, you need to add lein-cljsbuild plugins with build information. For further explanation, refer to http://www.mase.io/code/clojure/node/2015/01/24/getting-started-with-clojurecript-and-node/

If you don't want the change, just run `./scripts/build`.

Comment: also note ./scripts/watch will trigger the Clojure code, under the compiler in auto watch mode.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that your project.clj file is lacking a :cljsbuild stanza/key which defines the various parameters required to compile the clojurescript source files.

Have a look at [Modern Clojurescript Tutorial](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs) for more details or you can check out my clojurescript [file upload example](https://github.com/theophilusx/file-upload) to get an idea of how you can define :cljsbuild targets.